# Piecing Together Multipart UDP messages with Lua Wireshark Dissector

Tags: lua, udp, multipart, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a Lua Wireshark Dissector to work with a protocol that I am using that is on top of UDP.

My protocol has fields to distinguish when a message is multipart, how many segments make up the message, and what the current segment is.

Everything I've seen for putting together multiple messages in Lua is on top of TCP and uses a length in bytes. So nothing really seems to help with what I need to do.

Is it possible to piece together my messages? Any ideas on how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean that there are multiple messages inside a single UDP packet, or do you mean that multiple UDP packets can make up one message?

Comment: Also, you'd probably be better off asking this type of question on [ask.wireshark.org](http://ask.wireshark.org).

Comment: @hadriel - multiple UDP packets can make up one message.